# Microsoft Access Query - Convert Text to Numeric Depending on Field Contents - Low, Medium, High to 1,2 ,3

Tags: sql, ms-access, text, format, numeric

I am looking for a way to change the output of an access query to return either 1, 2 or 3 in replace of Low, Medium or High. I would like to convert the format of the field from Text to Numeric, since I wish to perform calculations using these numbers. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is [switch](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php), for example:

```
SELECT Field1, 
       Switch([field1]="Low",1,[Field1]="Medium",2,[Field1]="High",3) AS SwitchValue
FROM aTable
```

But it may be more convenient to simply create a small table with the substitute values and Join.

Comment: I opted for the table with substitute values

Comment: Best way to go ! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iif()` in MS Access:

```
select iif(col = 'High', 3, iif(col = 'Low', 1, 2)) as ColNumeric
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I add this to my query?

Comment: By putting the expression in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to create a **table** with a number field (PK) and the text description. Something like

```
tblID    |    priorityKey
---------+----------------
1        |    Low
2        |    Medium
3        |    High
```

Then when you need it, you simply JOIN them. Mind this needs to be updated in your table. You can simply run an Update Query.

However if you really need it get going now, I would suggest you use an IIF.